# postgresql, convert column into header without rowid

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to query a column into header and sum it. 

I saw some example using crosstab but i can't figure out how to make it work without rowid

Is there other workaround to make this works?

My Table

currency| amount
RMB      |   12
IDR        |   30
RMB      |   22
USD      |   58
IDR        |   30

Expected query

RMB_sum | IDR_sum | USD_sum
  34            |     60        |     58

Comment: Do u want expanded output of the query? if yes Turn on the expanded table formatting mode using  \x or \pset expanded.

Comment: @PawanSharma I'm sorry, may I ask what is expanded output?

Comment: postgres=# select * from test;
 username | password |   dob
----------+----------+----------
 d        | test     | 21081991
(1 row)

postgres=# \x
Expanded display is on.
postgres=# select * from test;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------
username | d
password | test
dob      | 21081991

Comment: run your query with psql -t -A -x -c "select * from test;" then it will you give expended output

Comment: @GBibu Will you know all the currencies that will ever be present in the table at the time of writing the query?

Comment: @PawanSharma okay I give it a test

Comment: @Scoots yea, I will have all the currency when writing the query, for this example I'm trying for just USD, RMB and IDR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've stated you know in advance all the values in currency at the time of writing this query, you can simply use conditional aggregates. As you're on PostgreSQL 9.1 you can only accomplish this by mixing sum() with a case statement:

```sql
select
    sum(case when currency = 'RMB' then amount else 0 end) as RMB_sum,
    sum(case when currency = 'IDR' then amount else 0 end) as IDR_sum,
    sum(case when currency = 'USD' then amount else 0 end) as USD_sum
from
    __transactions
```

(Note the above uses implicit grouping - everything in my select statement is an aggregate function so there is no need to explicitly group the query)

---

If you were using PostgreSQL 9.4+ you could simplify the above with the filter directive:

```sql
select
    sum(amount) filter(where currency = 'RMB') as RMB_sum,
    sum(amount) filter(where currency = 'IDR') as IDR_sum,
    sum(amount) filter(where currency = 'USD') as USD_sum
from
    __transactions
```

Comment: That's so embarrassing haha, I am thinking too much till I forgotten simple query like this, thank you very much for the help